# Передать значение переменной из Activity в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

### [image: Работа программы]

Пытаюсь сделать расписание занятий, но не очень получается. 
Есть два Java Class-а: MainActivity и ContentFragment(содержащий фрагмент), сделал выпадающее меню в котором есть два значения "Первая неделя" и "Вторая неделя", при нажатии на которые текст во фрагментах должен меняться соответственно.

Я пытался просто передать значение переменной itemPosition

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    pos = itemPosition;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContentFragment.class);
    intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
    return true;
```

разными способами или просто получить её в ContentFragment классе

```
MainActivity Main = new MainActivity(); 
int item = Main.pos;
```

Чтобы потом сравнивать её и писать соответствующий текст, если item = 0 - первой недели, если = 1 - второй, но значение переменной так и не удалось получить. Оно постоянно было = 0;

Вот и вопрос: как это реализовать? Или может есть до неприличия иной простой метод решения моей задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант решения Вашей задачи.

В **MainActivity**

1. Создаем интерфейс:

   ```
   interface MainActivityCommunicator{
       void onWeekChanged(int numberOfWeek);
   }

   MainActivityCommunicator mSendToFragment;
   ```
2. В методе `onNavigationItemSelected` добавляем строчку:

   ```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
       ...
       mSendToFragment.onWeekChanged(itemPosition);
       ...
   }
   ```

---

В **ContentFragment**

1. Реализуем интерфейс `MainActivityCommunicator`

   ```
   public class ContentFragment extends ... implements MainActivity.MainActivityCommunicator{
       ...
       @Override
       public void onWeekChanged(int numberOfWeek) {
           //Если выбранная неделя уже отображается, то return
           if(numberOfWeek == mCurrentSelectedWeek){
               return;
           }
           //Тут меняем отображение недели 
       }
       ...
   ```

   **UPD:**
2. Указываем что данный фрагмент реализует данный интерфейс:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
       Context context = getActivity();
       ((MainActivity) context).mSendToFragment = this;
   }
   ```
3. Об`null`яем ссылку на фрагмент когда он становится `Detach`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDetach() {
       super.onDetach();
       Context context = getActivity();
       ((MainActivity) context).mSendToFragment = null;
   }
   ```

Comment: Приложение выдает ошибку и закрывается(

Comment: @VladislavB лог ошибки можете привести? закрывается при старте или после каких либо действий?

Comment: к сожалению уже изменил весь код. Закрывается сразу при старте. Проблема в этой строке mSendToFragment.onWeekChanged(itemPosition), если её убрать, то работает.

Comment: @VladislavB действительно, мой косяк, исправил:)

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать библиотеку [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) и высылать событие смены недели из активити во фрагмент.

В `MainActivity` просто высылаем соответствующий `Event` когда изменилась неделя

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private void onWeekChange(int weekIndex) {
        EventBus().getDefault().post(new ChangeWeekEvent(weekIndex));
    }
}
```

Во фрагменте обрабатываем следующим образом

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onStart(){
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        //some code
    }

    public void onStop(){
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        //some code
    }

    //вызывается, когда из активити послали ивент
    public void onEvent(ChangeWeekEvent event){
        //обрабатываем ивент
    }
}
```

Класс `Event` может выглядеть так:

```
public class ChangeWeekEvent {

    private final int newWeek;
    //Другие поля

    public ChangeWeekEvent(int newWeek) {
        this.newWeek = newWeek;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно использую для таких вещей адаптер FragmentPagerAdapter.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragmentPager);
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Обработчик переключения между фрагментами
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener viewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        };

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerListener);

        // Класс, управляющий фрагментами
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(fm);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        pager.setAdapter(myAdapter );
    }

    // Выбор пункта меню
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
       // В зависимости от выбранного пункта меню, мы можем передать любые свои данные в заданный фрагмент
       if (itemPosition == 0) {
           myAdapter.updateFragment(0); // Передаем данные в первый фрагмент (лучше завести именованные константы)
       }
       // и так далее...
       return true; 
    }
}
```

В коде адаптера создаю нужное количество фрагментов.

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Fragment[] fragments;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
// Создаем нужное количество фрагментов (для индексации и доступа снаружи лучше завести публичные константы, чтобы не путаться в дальнейшем)
        fragments = new Fragment[2];
        fragments[0] = new Fragment();
        fragments[1] = new Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int num) {
        if (num >= 0 && num < fragments.length)
            return fragments[num];
        else return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.length;
    }

    /**
     * Обновить фрагмент
     * Дополнительными параметрами можно передать любые данные из активити
     */
    public void updateFragment(int index) {
        fragments[index].updateData();
    }

}
```

В дальнейшем любые данные можно передавать через новые методы адаптера. Но не стоит забывать о том, что в процессе работы фрагменты могут выгружаться из памяти, причем независимо от активити, поэтому надо предусмотреть случаи, когда фрагменты пересоздаются заново.